# If $a^2 + p^2 = b^2$ then $2(a+p+1)$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

We are given $$ a^2 + p^2 = b^2 $$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is prime. We are to show that $$2(a+p+1)$$ is a perfect square. Is there any elegant ways to go about this problem? Struggling to find a proof myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It follows from the usual representation theorem for Pythagorean triples. Not elegant, but it does the job.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't seem to be familiar with this representation theorem?

Comment: Suppose $a^2+b^2=c^2$. There are integers $s,t,k$ (with $s$ and $t$ relatively prime and of opposite parity) such that $a=2kst$, $b=k(s^2-t^2)$ and $c=k(s^2+t^2)$. In our case the $k$ is irrelevant.

Comment: We can also argue directly from the equation, but I think of the representation theorem as so standard that it is not worthwhile to do so.

Comment: mmm..., You may use the fact p is prime as follow:
$a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b) = -p^2$ and solve the differents equations systems, like a diofantin equation, you can find $a$ in terms of $p$, and replace...

Comment: I see! Many thanks for your help as always!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We have $a^2 + p^2 = b^2$ so $p^2 = b^2-a^2 = (b+a)(b-a)$.

Therefore $b-a=1$ and $p^2 = b+a=2a+1$

Therefore $2(a+p+1) = p^2 + 2p + 1 = (p+1)^2$

Comment: Many thanks! This is a very neat way to prove it!

Comment: How does $b-a=1$ follow from everything that precedes it?

Comment: $p^2$ has three factors: $p^2, p$ and $1$. $(b+a)$ and $(b-a)$ cannot both be $p$ therefore they are $p^2$ and $1$ respectively.